# Python: Rename drive volume with space character in label

Tags: python, subprocess, disk

I am trying to rename a drives volume label but i get an error if the label contains a space

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['label', 'L:test 1'])
```

Produces this Error:

> Access Denied as you do not have sufficient privileges or
> the disk may be locked by another process.
> You have to invoke this utility running in elevated mode
> and make sure the disk is unlocked.

The code works fine if I remove the space `subprocess.run(['label', 'L:test1'])`

**How can I add spaces to my label?**

Comment: Are you able to make it work from the command line? This seems like a "how to use the computer" question more than a programming question.

Comment: Yes. If I use the DOS command: "label L:test 1" it works fine. If i RIGHT CLICK, "Rename" in Windows and rename it "test 1" it also works. I have tried numerous tricks to convert the ' ' space chracter using '// ' for example and it doesn't work. If you copy paste the code and try it on a dummy usb drive yourself it will throw the error. I believe for this reason its a python syntax error or limitation with subprocess

Comment: did you try to add `" "` - `'"L:test 1"'`? Or maybe it should be space with \ or \\ instead of // - at least on LInux command I have to use \ when name has space.

Comment: Yeah I tried:
subprocess.run(['label', "'L:test 1'"])
subprocess.run(['label', '"L:test 1"'])
subprocess.run(['label', '"L:test\ 1"'])
subprocess.run(['label', '"L:test\\ 1"'])
subprocess.run(['label', '"L:test\\1"'])
subprocess.run(['label', r'"L:test\\1"'])
subprocess.run(['label', r'"L:test\\ 1"'])
subprocess.run(['label', r'L:test\\1'])
subprocess.run(['label', r'L:test\\ 1'])
subprocess.run(['label', r'"L:test 1"'])
They don't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `subprocess.run(['label', 'L:test', '1'])`.
It works via concatenation - silly, but true.